# Rails: Permission denied - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: permission-denied

I follow a tutorial on how to get started with rails, but end up with different outcome than the video. Here is the message I get back when using the command rails s:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EACCES)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:263:in `block in add_tcp_listener'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:262:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:262:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/single.rb:87:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:64:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:296:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

EDIT:
I am on Windows, and have tried running the command prompt as admin. Same result.

EDIT SOLVED:

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx and restart your pc - [Chetan Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7018858/chetan-mehta)

Comment: If you're on windows. Try running the cmd as administrator

Comment: There's something else going on here. I hit this issue intermittently, when there's NOTHING using port 3000.

Comment: @AlexanderRiccio The sad truth I have come to realize is that there is something actually using the port (hence the error), but we are unable to see exactly what is. 

In my case, restarting the PC worked because the service taking up the port was a bit slow to start up. So as long as I started my application right away after turning on my PC, then it worked. The thing that in the end turned out to be the culprit was a mouse software... It was occupying all the normal development ports (8080, 3000 and more). Only after uninstalling the software did I get my ports back permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ubuntu :

Try running `sudo rails s`
Make sure you have sudo permissions

If the port is busy, you can try running server on a different port. i.e.:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

If you are using window then instead of sudo try running your command prompt as administrator

Comment: Try changing the port

Comment: Same message back with different port.

Comment: Can you telnet to the port? Try:

telnet localhost 3000

Comment: This should tell if the port is busy

Comment: Also try  rails s 0.0.0.0

Comment: "D:\FitnessHelper\fitness>telnet localhost 3000

Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3000: Connect failed"

Comment: Is the firewall enabled?

Comment: "`require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/0.0.0.0 (LoadError)"

Comment: Yes, the firewall is on. EDIT: Attempted to turn off and run both telnet and rails s. Same result.

Comment: That's blocking the port

Comment: Try turning off the firewall and then rails s

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx
Try this and restart your pc

Comment: Great.. all the best