# Rails: Permission denied - bind(2) for “127.0.0.1” port 3000 (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, server, ruby-on-rails-5

When I try to run my rails server in port 3000 I get this error. I can run the server in a different port and it works but I want that to run in port 3000.

I have tried to check if this port is busy and to kill the process but every time I do that I find the port is free. And I still get this error.

can anyone help me out to solve this? I'm on Windows 10.

Rails 5.0.2
Ruby 2.4.1

Comment: maybe your problem is with your firewall, have you tried opening the port there? have you checked on your application folder tmp/pids to see if there are some files? putting of the antivirus and trying again? as a side comment, try to work with ruby on linux, you will face problems working with big applications on windows, gems that don't work, services and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

This just means there is another server running on Port 3000. 
you can get around this and clear kill the running server manually

in the root of your application type:

```
cd tmp/pids
```

then you can check to see if there is a file in there called server.

if there is you can remove it. and you can start your server again on port 3000

Comment: when i type cd tmp/pids i see no results

Comment: Then can we try to find what's keeping port 3000 globally?

You can type [sudo] lsof -i :3000 
if there's anything there then you can run kill -9 PID .. Or show an output of the first command

Comment: ya sure we can try globally. even this cmd gives me no result

Comment: mycomp@LAPTOP-7F0M4N43:/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/camp.in$ cd tmp/pids 
mycomp@LAPTOP-7F0M4N43:/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/camp.in/tmp/pids$                when i type cd tmp/pids , it simplys redirects to the path thats it

Comment: yeah and then run `ls` to see if there's something in that directory. Sorry i forgot to add that. Try `sudo lsof -i :3000` .. this has given me a lot of headache in some time back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184914/discussion-between-penny-and-claeusdev).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739386/rails-permission-denied-bind2-for-127-0-0-1-port-3000-errnoeacces